# Intuit Customer Account Data APIs

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Folks,
  Using the Intuit RESTful API, is it possible to have a client connect to Intuit, so my app would create and update records on their quickbooks database?

What I would like to accomplish is grooming my clients records and creating on the fly backups of certain transactions which are custom to this particular client.

Also, if there are multiple client accounts, I can connect to all of their quickbooks databases with one API Auth key, correct?  The terms are quite confusing... should I be looking at Customer Account Data APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **Quickbook Online REST API(V3)** for this.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

To interact with QB account, you need to have OAuth keys(consumerKey, consumerSecret, AccessToken and AcessSecret) corresponding to target QB account.

Here - consumerKey and consumerSecret are static tokens which you'll get if you create an app in appcenter( this app is created just to get consumerKey, consumerSecret and apptoken)

AccessKey and AccessSecret are specific to particular QBAccount( QBO account gets identified by ReleamID)

---

To generate access token and access secret corresponding to a QBO account, user's intervention is a must.

To start development using QB API, you need to create an IA apps in Intuit's appcenter.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0010_signup

From the above link you will get - apptoken, consumer key and consumer Secret. You can use the above 3 keys in IPPOAuthPlayground(PFB link) to get the access token and access secret corresponding to your QB Online account. 
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

Using the above tokens, you can call any REST endpoints against your QB Online account. For development purpose, you can use IPP provided devkit.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

If you just want to test this endpoints against your company then you can use APIExplorer tool as well.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

---

**Customer Account Data API** is a completely different service.

IT provides developers access to end-user financial account and transactional information from nearly 19K financial institutions, giving developers the ability to create custom financial applications.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata

Hope it answers your qts.

Thanks

Comment: Absolutely!  So via these API calls, i can delete/add records in different quickbooks accounts?

Comment: Yes. But as I've mentioned in my post, you need to have Oauth tokens which you'll get through a 3-legged authentication process. To get details of it, you can refer - developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/…. Same functionality was implemented in the OAuth Playground(link mentioned above). You can explorer all these endpoints using ApiExplorer.